# Cases environment problem, when used with subscript

Tags: subscripts, cases

I am trying to use the cases environment but I get the message, missing $ inserted.

```
    \begin{cases} 
      deg(u_i)  \textrm{ if u_i on primary diagonal} \\
     -1 & \textrm{ if u_i u_j adjacent} \\
      0 & \textrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
```

Is the use of subscript, the problem? Any solutions?

Comment: That is because you have subscripted term `u_i` inside a `\textrm` argument, which nullifies the math mode.

Comment: So what is the solution? I tried u\sb{i} without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to place a math environment and add `$` inside `\textrm`.

```
\[
\begin{cases} 
      deg(u_i)  \textrm{if $u_i$ on primary diagonal} \\
     -1 & \textrm{if $u_i$ $u_j$ adjacent} \\
      0 & \textrm{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: I'd use `\text` instead of `\textrm`.